# Is it possible to add new concept to ImageContents

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I was hoping to use `ImageContents` to locate some specific objects in a series of images with a bounding box. However, `ImageContents` simply does not have a category of objects for what I'm looking or.

I have a lot of examples, that I could use to "train" `ImageContents`. However, I see no option to amend `ImageContents` or add a new category of objects.

Is there a way to add a new category of object to `ImageContents`?

Comment: What category of objects, may I ask, are you looking for?

Comment: I want to find figures in pdfs and add bounding boxes, and classify them as schematic vs a graph.

Comment: You can try with `TrainImageContentDetector`.